# Derivative of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-5}}$ via definition of derivative

Tags: calculus, limits

A high school student has asked me to help with a limit. The teacher wants them to calculate the derivative of
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-5}}$$
at the point $x=9$ using the definition of the derivative. AND! They don't know $(1+x)^\alpha \approx 1 + \alpha x$.

I'm puzzled since don't know how to proceed without it.

$$\left.\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x-5}}\right)'\,\right|_{x=9}  =
\lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{1}{h}\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{4+h}}-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)=
\lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{1}{2h}\left((1+h/4)^{-1/2}-1\right)\color{red}{{\bf=}}-1/16
$$

Is there really a way to walk around?..

BTW, what is the easiest way to derive $(1+x)^\alpha \approx 1 + \alpha x$ for $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$? I forgot how we did this in school.

Answer (score 3):

Hint

Multiply numerator and denominator of
$$
\frac{2 - \sqrt{4+h}}{2\sqrt{4+h}}
$$
by the conjugate
$$
2 + \sqrt{4+h}\ .
$$

This trick will work for square roots but not for other exponents.

Answer (score 3):

You have 
$$
\frac1h\,\left(\frac1{\sqrt{4+h}}-\frac12\right)
=\frac{2-\sqrt{4+h}}{2h\sqrt{4+h}}
=-\frac1{2\sqrt{4+h}(2+\sqrt{4+h})},
$$
after multiplying and dividing by $2+\sqrt{4+h}$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. One may use, as $h \to 0$,
$$
\dfrac{1}{h}\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{4+h}}-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)=\dfrac{1}{h}\left(\dfrac{2-\sqrt{4+h}}{2\sqrt{4+h}}\right)=\dfrac{1}{h}\cdot\dfrac{4-(4+h)}{2\sqrt{4+h}\cdot(2+\sqrt{4+h})}.
$$